# How Inheritance works in Java with method reference operator

Tags: java, inheritance, lambda, method-reference

Interface

```
public interface InterfaceOne {
    void start();
    void stop();
}
```

Main Class

```
public class MainProg {
    public static void main(String [] args){
        new ServiceA().start();
    }
}
```

ServiceA

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServiceA implements InterfaceOne{
    private final List<ServiceB> worker = new ArrayList<>();
    public ServiceA(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            worker.add(new ServiceB(2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::stop);
    }
}
```

ServiceB

```
public class ServiceB extends ServiceC{
    int count;
    protected ServiceB(int num){
        this.count = num;
    }
}
```

ServiceC

```
public class ServiceC implements InterfaceOne{
    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("Starting..");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        System.out.println("Stopping..");
    }
}
```

Here from the main class, I am calling a method of ServiceA that internally calls to the method of serviceB using the method reference operator. ServiceA Can be also written like below where instead of using the method reference operator i can use lambda function

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ServiceA implements InterfaceOne{
    private final List<ServiceB> worker = new ArrayList<>();
    public ServiceA(){
        for(int i = 0; i < 2; i++){
            worker.add(new ServiceB(2));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void start() {
        worker.forEach(obj -> obj.start());
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        worker.forEach(obj -> obj.stop());
    }
}
```

Here I am aware of how this program is working using lambda function, but want to understand how it is working with the method reference operator

```
worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);
```

The output of this program is

```
Starting..
Starting..
```

Comment: Inside your ServiceA you are calling the methods on your `private final List<ServiceB> worker` list, which as you can see contains Objects of type `ServiceB` and those calls on `ServiceB` are what are generating the output. That you for some reason decided to have `ServiceB extends ServiceC` probably just added to your confusion. ( If you name classes A, B, and C you usually expect those names to mean that B extends A and C extends B, not what you decided to do)

Comment: Thanks for the reply can you please explain this line: worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);
here I am calling InterfaceOne::start

Comment: That line iterates over all objects in the `workers` list and calls the method `start` on each one. This was btw already explained in the answer you got below.

Comment: What output did you expect? Why?

Comment: ```worker.forEach(obj -> obj.start());``` and 
```worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);```
above two lines creates same output, here i  want to understand more about ```worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);```

Comment: I don't understand. You don't mention a lambda expression in your post. Is this a new question, trying to compare those two?

Comment: My Bad, Should I update the question? Actually, that's the confusion for me how  ```InterfaceOne::start```is being interpreted

Comment: Yes please, edit to clarify the questions in the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote:

```
worker.forEach(InterfaceOne::start);
```

This calls the start method for every element of the worker list. It does not matter if it's called in the scope of a method of ServiceA, the elements of the worker list are ServiceB's, which inherit the `start` method of ServiceC.